# Plot timeseries volume (instead of density) using ridgline/joyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, timeserieschart

I want to plot a chart looks like a ridgeline/joyplot, but instead of displaying density, displays the volume of occurences over time (timeseries stacked area chart).

**How can I plot the volume of each genre, instead of the density, but maintaining the look and feel of the ridgline/joyplot?** I am struggling to do it using subplots, as I need to display the area below the line and the line should be smooth.

I have the following sample database, code and plot:

**Sample database (to run the code, copy and paste it to a .csv file):**

| movie_genre | date_released | numerical_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Horror | 16/02/2019 | 43512 |
| Horror | 12/02/2019 | 43508 |
| Animation | 21/02/2019 | 43517 |
| Horror | 14/01/2019 | 43479 |
| Horror | 17/02/2019 | 43513 |
| Comedy | 24/02/2019 | 43520 |
| Animation | 15/01/2019 | 43480 |
| Comedy | 25/02/2019 | 43521 |
| Horror | 03/01/2019 | 43468 |
| Comedy | 25/02/2019 | 43521 |
| Comedy | 15/02/2019 | 43511 |
| Horror | 08/02/2019 | 43504 |
| Horror | 16/02/2019 | 43512 |
| Documentary | 20/02/2019 | 43516 |
| Comedy | 05/02/2019 | 43501 |
| Drama | 03/02/2019 | 43499 |
| Comedy | 19/01/2019 | 43484 |
| Animation | 13/02/2019 | 43509 |
| Horror | 16/01/2019 | 43481 |
| Animation | 03/02/2019 | 43499 |
| Comedy | 14/01/2019 | 43479 |
| Comedy | 20/01/2019 | 43485 |
| Drama | 10/01/2019 | 43475 |
| Animation | 28/01/2019 | 43493 |
| Animation | 29/01/2019 | 43494 |
| Drama | 21/02/2019 | 43517 |
| Horror | 18/01/2019 | 43483 |
| Comedy | 17/02/2019 | 43513 |
| Documentary | 30/01/2019 | 43495 |
| Documentary | 12/02/2019 | 43508 |
| Documentary | 04/01/2019 | 43469 |
| Drama | 27/02/2019 | 43523 |
| Comedy | 15/01/2019 | 43480 |
| Animation | 14/02/2019 | 43510 |
| Drama | 03/02/2019 | 43499 |
| Drama | 17/02/2019 | 43513 |
| Documentary | 22/02/2019 | 43518 |
| Horror | 25/01/2019 | 43490 |
| Horror | 21/01/2019 | 43486 |
| Documentary | 25/01/2019 | 43490 |
| Documentary | 12/02/2019 | 43508 |
| Comedy | 13/02/2019 | 43509 |
| Drama | 13/02/2019 | 43509 |
| Drama | 05/01/2019 | 43470 |
| Horror | 15/02/2019 | 43511 |
| Drama | 31/01/2019 | 43496 |
| Comedy | 26/02/2019 | 43522 |
| Horror | 27/02/2019 | 43523 |
| Documentary | 25/02/2019 | 43521 |
| Drama | 18/01/2019 | 43483 |
| Horror | 22/02/2019 | 43518 |
| Documentary | 10/02/2019 | 43506 |
| Drama | 25/01/2019 | 43490 |
| Documentary | 01/01/2019 | 43466 |
| Documentary | 21/01/2019 | 43486 |
| Documentary | 10/01/2019 | 43475 |
| Drama | 27/02/2019 | 43523 |
| Drama | 26/01/2019 | 43491 |
| Animation | 17/01/2019 | 43482 |

**Code:**

```
import joypy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Downloads\movies.csv', delimiter=';') #directory where you saved the table above

df['date_released'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_released'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

fig, ax = joypy.joyplot(df, 
                        by = 'movie_genre', 
                        column='numerical_date', 
                        colormap= cm.autumn,
                        overlap=1,
                        figsize = (13,8),
                        x_range=[43466, 43525],
                        xrot=90,
                        alpha=0.7)

print(ax[-1].get_xticks())

new_dates = [mdates.num2date(x +  mdates.date2num(np.datetime64('1900-01-01'))) for x in ax[-1].get_xticks()]
new_dates = [t.strftime('%d.%m.%Y').lower() for t in new_dates]
ax[-1].set_xticklabels(new_dates)
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe include an example of what you want this to look like?  Your description of what you want is not clear to me.

Comment: Hi Jody! I want it to look exactly like the picture of the Joyplot in the question. However, by definition, the Joyplot plots the **density** of each line category throughout the columns (in this case, time). For my purposes, visualizing density can be misleading, as I want to **compare how each category behaved over time**.

Comment: Thus, I need it plot the **actual number of occurences**, just like a simple timeseries chart would, but with this smooth line, area below chart, and stacked categories look, once it is the best way I could think of to show my data. Perhaps  area subplots could do it... but I could not work it out in a nice way!

Comment: This is still not well-defined.  Your data is just raw dates of occurrence by genre.  What do you mean by "actual number of occurrences"?  The total?  Occurrences per time block, ie. per month or per year?  If its the latter you need to somehow calculate the total per month before you plot.  Once you have that, you can just use ax.fill_between.

Comment: **Per month.** I'm presenting the above table in "plain" format, as it was used to plot the Joyplot. But yeah, perhaps I'll need to sum it, it'll depend on the solution.